# Three.js Wrap Text

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Are there any implementations of wrapping Text3d object around a 3D or 2d Path?

I checked out few tutorials from r.49 of Three.js and it looks like the current version doesnt support it.

I am able to create the text, extrude it but unable to wrap the text along a path.

Thanks in advance
Sam

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps:
http://www.lab4games.net/zz85/blog/2011/09/17/3d-text-bending-uv-mapping/
At least it shows it is possible to do with three.js

Comment: dern, says database error on connection on this page.